# Flatten a nested object

Tags: javascript, object, promise

I'm working on a GET request that finds an id and the amount of holdings a user has saved in the database. It takes that id and calls a function that retrieves updated information about the item. What i'm trying to do is also include the holdings in the GET request, however, I want it inside of the object with the updated information. Basically what I want to do is flatten these objects so that it's an array of two objects instead of an object within an object. Below is the code i'm using and the output i'm receiving. I've tried changing around the Object.assign part, but for the most part i'm lost on how to achieve this.

**Current:**

```
const getFullCryptoPortfolio = () =>
  CryptoPortfolio.find()
    .then(portfolios =>
      Promise.all(portfolios.map(portfolio => getCoins(portfolio.id).then(item =>
        Object.assign({}, item, {
          holdings: portfolio.holdings
        })))));

[
    {
        "0": {
            "id": "bitcoin",
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "rank": "1",
            "price_usd": "9289.45",
            "price_btc": "1.0",
            "24h_volume_usd": "6536340000.0",
            "market_cap_usd": "157138942782",
            "available_supply": "16915850.0",
            "total_supply": "16915850.0",
            "max_supply": "21000000.0",
            "percent_change_1h": "0.36",
            "percent_change_24h": "-3.7",
            "percent_change_7d": "-18.82",
            "last_updated": "1520905166"
        },
        "holdings": 1
    },
    {
        "0": {
            "id": "ethereum",
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "symbol": "ETH",
            "rank": "2",
            "price_usd": "704.491",
            "price_btc": "0.0765146",
            "24h_volume_usd": "1773830000.0",
            "market_cap_usd": "69147117523.0",
            "available_supply": "98151882.0",
            "total_supply": "98151882.0",
            "max_supply": null,
            "percent_change_1h": "0.53",
            "percent_change_24h": "-3.12",
            "percent_change_7d": "-17.17",
            "last_updated": "1520905152"
        },
        "holdings": 2
    }
]
```

**Example Expected Output:**

```
 [
    {
            "id": "bitcoin",
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "rank": "1",
            "price_usd": "9289.45",
            "price_btc": "1.0",
            "24h_volume_usd": "6536340000.0",
            "market_cap_usd": "157138942782",
            "available_supply": "16915850.0",
            "total_supply": "16915850.0",
            "max_supply": "21000000.0",
            "percent_change_1h": "0.36",
            "percent_change_24h": "-3.7",
            "percent_change_7d": "-18.82",
            "last_updated": "1520905166",
            "holdings": 1
    },
    {
            "id": "ethereum",
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "symbol": "ETH",
            "rank": "2",
            "price_usd": "704.491",
            "price_btc": "0.0765146",
            "24h_volume_usd": "1773830000.0",
            "market_cap_usd": "69147117523.0",
            "available_supply": "98151882.0",
            "total_supply": "98151882.0",
            "max_supply": null,
            "percent_change_1h": "0.53",
            "percent_change_24h": "-3.12",
            "percent_change_7d": "-17.17",
            "last_updated": "1520905152",
            "holdings": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result you're looking for?

Comment: @treyhakanson Just updated to include an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you provide an example of the source data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems like the `getCoins` method resolves an array of objects which you are trying to merge with holdings. You could modify your `Object.assign` like the following -

```
Object.assign({}, ...item, {
  holdings: portfolio.holdings
});
```

This will spread the objects inside the item array. Note that if multiple items have the same property it will be overridden by the later.

If the `getCoins` always returns a single item, you could instead do -

```
Object.assign({}, item[0], {
  holdings: portfolio.holdings
});
```

Alternatively you could keep the array, and assign holdings to each object instead.

```
item.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj , {
  holdings: portfolio.holdings
}))
```

Comment: I just realized when I tried adjusting Object.assign the first couple times, I was using the spread operator in the wrong place. The first thing you wrote was absolutely what I needed!

Comment: may also try `Object.values(item)`, but it may not work in IE, just like the spread operator (`...`)

Comment: @vol7ron I'll look into that. I did realize spread operators don't work with older versions of IE.

Comment: Not just older versions..any version.  Microsoft Edge is considered a different product from IE.

Comment: `Object.values()` and a few other syntactic sugars also suffer from this problem.  Fortunately, Babel and Lodash will help solve that, if you can utilize either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign all the properties of "0" to out object 'item';
2. Assign "holdings" property to out object 'item';
3. return item.

   ```
   function flatten(input) {
     return input.map(function(x){
       let item = x["0"];
       item["holdings"] = x["holdings"];
       return item;
     });
   }
   ```